# QT UI-Design custom load Bar

Tags: qt

I would like to create a custom Widget (Loading Bar) Which has the shape of a half Donut, what is the way of creating custom Widgets? In css i would animate the position of an inked bar and use the donut as an alpha mask.

Any tips doing that in Qt?

[image]

Comment: If I understand correctly you shoud subclass a `QProgressBar` and overrider its `paintEvent` to display the custom shape. You already have all the functionality but draw it to your liking.

Comment: Hey Bowdzone, thank you i will give it a try and post it here.